# Youtube Player API is inserting allow attribute

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I'm using Youtube Player API to show a video. But the playerVars are not being detected because I have an autoplay: 0 and the video still autoplay.
I noticed while inspecting on chrome is that the  has an attribute 'allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" '  and probably this is doing the autoplay.

But why is this attribute showing? How can I take it off?
I tried so many things...

This is what I have:

HTML:

```
<div class="video-wrapper">
  <a href="{{$video['url']}}" style="display: none;"></a>
  <div id="player" class="video-frame"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
iFramePlayerApi() {
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.id = 'iframe-demo';
    tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var videoLink = $('a[href^="https://youtu.be/"]').attr('href');

    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = () => {
      this.player = new window.YT.Player('player', {
        videoId : this.extractVideoID(videoLink),
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        playerVars: {enablejsapi: 1, autoplay: 0, controls: 0, loop: 0, modestbranding: 1, rel: 0,},
        //iv_load_policy: 3,
        //playlist: this.extractVideoID(videoLink),
        events: {
          'onReady': this.onPlayerReady,
          'onStateChange': this.onPlayerStateChange,
        },
      });
    }
  },
```

Chrome Inspect tool:

```
<iframe 
   id="player" 
   class="video-frame" 
   frameborder="0" 
   allowfullscreen="1" 
   allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" 
   title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="390" 
   src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/f5kUr7FWTug?enablejsapi=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;controls=0&amp;loop=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000&amp;widgetid=1">
</iframe>
```

Comment: I am also stuck in this hell. My Websites keep asking people with VR to allow VR permissions...